# How do I add gems to my external libraries on RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have a number of gems in my external libraries on Rubymine, but not all of the gems that I have installed through my gemfile and gem install have showed up. How can I add all my app's gems to the file so I can edit their libs?

Answer (score 3):

Rubymine shows only the gems from your `Gemfile`. You can attach the installed gems to the project manually, using Settings (CTRL+ALT+S), and search for `Ruby SDK and Gems`.

If you are using rvm, sometimes you have to select the correct ruby+gemset as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just notice the key combination (CTRL+ALT+F5) may take you to tty5 on Ubuntu :)

Comment: Wow, I had to google the current keypress for rubymine on linux/windows, because I am developing on mac os x since 2012, where it is called "Preferences" instead of "Settings" :P :P https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/settings-preferences-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally RubyMine should show all the gems that you have installed in your system and that you have specified in the `Gemfile`. Otherwise it could be a bug which [should be reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RUBY) with more details.